# How to set a condition with @auth.requires_login in Web2py

Tags: authentication, web2py

In my web2py web app, the controller function `def index():` has the decorator `@auth.requires_login()`.

For development and testing purpose I comment out this decorator. But I often forget to uncomment it before committing the code.

I would like to change this decorator into something that would test if a file is present (i.e. skipLogin) and if not to require login. I can then add the skipLogin file in my .gitignore file and don't need to worry about commenting and uncommenting the decorator line.

I suppose it should be something like `@auth.requires(lambda: xxx)` but I have no idea what xxx should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auth.requires` takes a `requires_login` argument, so you can just set the condition to `True`, and then conditionally set the value of `requires_login`. For example, you can set it to require login for non-local requests:

```
@auth.requires(True, requires_login=not request.is_local)
```

Comment: @auth.requires(True, requires_login=not request.is_local) does not work for me. I´m using pytest